# angularJS controllers and PDF

Tags: angularjs, pdf, controller

I work with angularJS and I have some difficulties with controllers.

I have one page on on this page I have two controllers one to receive data from a web service and one to display the data on pdfViewer.

My idea is to start the second controller after the first controller have receive the datas because now it's seems that the two controller start at the same time so nothing is display.

Here my code for the view :

```js
var seeCv = angular.module('myApp', ['ngPDFViewer']);
seeCv.controller('TestCtrl',function($http){
            
    $http.get('some url').success(function(data){
            datas = data; 
    });

            
});


seeCv.controller('VisuCvCtrl',['$scope','PDFViewerService',function($scope,pdf){
        
        $scope.pdfURL = datas;

 $scope.instance = pdf.Instance("viewer");
        
        $scope.nextPage = function(){
            $scope.instance.nextPage();
        };
        
        $scope.prevPage = function(){
            $scope.instance.prevPage();
        };
        
        $scope.pageLoaded = function(curPage, totalPages){
            $scope.currentPage = curPage;
            $scope.totalPage = totalPages;
        };
    
        
}]);
```

```html
<div ng-controller="TestCtrl" >
    <div class="container" ng-controller="VisuCvCtrl">
        <button ng-click="prevPage()">&lt;</button>
        <button ng-click="nextPage()">&gt;</button>
        <br>
        <span>{{currentPage}}/{{totalPage}}</span>
        <br>
        <pdfviewer src="{{pdfURL}}" on-page-load='pageLoaded(page,total)' id="viewer"></pdfviewer>
    </div>
    </div>
```

PS: I tried to make the web service call on the second controller but there was a error with the $http.

Answer (score 0):

Each controller has its own scope, you are trying to reach testController scope from VisuCtrl, actually you are trying to use parent's controller scope from child controller. You can do it this way:

```
seeCv.controller('TestCtrl',function($http){

    $http.get('some url').success(function(data){
            datas = data; 
    });           
});



seeCv.controller('VisuCvCtrl',['$scope','PDFViewerService',function($scope,pdf){

      $scope.pdfURL = $scope.$parent.datas;
      ...

    }]);
```

Anyhow, I suggest a service in order to fetch the data (This way you can reuse the service get function in others controllers as well).
Controller will use the service to get the data and put it on scope so the view can use this data.

Comment: I think I don't get it. In you example you have two fonctions but these functions have to be in the second controller, spit or completly anywhere else.

Comment: @Thomasgraveleine for implementing the way you tried, you should get the data in test ctrl and reach it from VisuCtrl by using "$scope.$parent". Edited the answer

Comment: I reach my goal on this issue. Actually I receive data type application/octet-stream and I just need to parse it in order to display it with pdfviewer anyone have a clue to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it in the same controller :

```
seeCv.controller('VisuCvCtrl',['$scope','$http','PDFViewerService',function($scope,$http,pdf){

     var promise = $http.get('some url').success(function(data){
         datas = data;
     });

    promise.then( 
            function(display){
               $scope.pdfURL = datas;

                $scope.instance = pdf.Instance("viewer");

                $scope.nextPage = function(){
                    $scope.instance.nextPage();
                };

                $scope.prevPage = function(){
                    $scope.instance.prevPage();
                };

                $scope.pageLoaded = function(curPage, totalPages){
                    $scope.currentPage = curPage;
                    $scope.totalPage = totalPages;
                }; 
            });

}]);
```

But the thing is now I have this kind of error repeating each 10 seconds.

error: [$interpolate:interr] errors.angularjs.org/1.2.9/$interpolate/interr?p0=%7B%7BpdfURL%7D%7D…2500%2500%2500%2500%2500%2500%2500%2500%2500%2500%2500%2500%2500%2500%2500
    at Error (native)
    at code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/angular.min.js:6:449
    at Object.$get.s (https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/angular.min.js:73:497)
    at h.Bd.$get.h.$digest (code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/angular.min.js:100:171)
    at h.Bd.$get.h.$apply (code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/angular.min.js:103:100)
    at HTMLButtonElement. (code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/angular.min.js:179:65)
    at code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/angular.min.js:27:208
    at q (code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/angular.min.js:7:380)
    at HTMLButtonElement.Zc.c (code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/angular.min.js:27:190) angular.js:9419
(anonymous function)

And I really don't know what it is.